# Store UITextfield's contents into NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I want to let the user enter some names in a `UITextField` (preferably seperated with commas or just spaces), and then convert it into an `NSMutableArray` to display it in a `UITableView`.

Is it possible? If it is, please tell me how.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: didn't had a clue what to search for. PS. great link haha.

Comment: Okay, then break up the problem you want to solve: Start by placing a UITextField and obtaining the input. Next, separate the contents of this (there's a groovy method in the NSString class reference for this) by splitting it based on occurences of a character. (comma or space, etc) Then grab this array and look at loading it into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You can use set of Characters like this code i use 'space' and ',' and then create an array.

```
NSString *string = textField.text;
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,"];   
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set]];                 

NSLog(@"%@ ===", array);
```

Comment: But how to retrieve the data from UITextField then?

Comment: when do you want retrieve data from textField at last, when you click on button. if Yes it's simple string=textField.text;

Comment: incompatible pointer types initializing *__strong  with an expression of a NSArray - Warning, did copy your code, exactly as you posted. (Warning is on the 3rd sentence.)

Comment: NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set]];

Comment: One thing, getting the error on the NSLOG -> Local Declaration of array hides instance variable.

Comment: change the name of local array.

Comment: fixed that, but now getting breakpoints aT:    NSMutableArray *deelnemers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[inputValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set]];

Comment: fixed this one, hided the input too fast.

Comment: What is hided the input too fast?

Answer (score 2):

fetch the text from textfield and convert it to NSArray using @"," as separator.

```
NSArray *names = [textfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: for some reason it says: textfield not declared, but in the header file i've got IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;